# ios - make keyboard disappear when UIButton is pressed

Tags: ios

I am trying to make the keyboard disappear when a UIButton is pressed -

```
-(IBAction)nextButtonPressed{
    [usernameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I have declared the button as IBOutlet and connected it to the IBAction in the storyboard. But the code however does not work and keyboard remains visible. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did the method nextButtonPressed get called?

Comment: NSLog both usernameTextField and passwordTextField in nextButtonPressed.

Comment: That means the textfields have not been connected to your properties in interface builder.

Comment: Fixed that, still same problem

Comment: @AshishAgarwal Show us some codes about how you create the usernameTextField and passwordTextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to subscribe to the UITextFieldDelegate Protocol in your View/ViewController's header file like this:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Make sure you're setting your view/viewcontroller to be the UITextField's delegate after you init the textfield in the .m:

```
yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

And you can do this :

```
-(IBAction)nextButtonPressed{
    [usernameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

You forgot this:

```
usernameTextField.delegate = self;
passwordTextField.delegate = self;
```